# How to load an entity using the uuid?

Tags: 8

I have created a custom resource which extends the `EntityResource` class. This way I can use all build in functionality that Drupal core provides on the default entity resource, but I can still add some extra checks. This works perfectly fine.

I defined my canonical route in my resource as /api/my-endpoint/{node}. In this way, I can fetch and patch nodes by the node ID. After careful consideration, I want to implement /api/my-endpoint/{node_uuid} or even /api/my-endpoint/{node_custom_field} to fetch (and patch) a node by UUID.

Of course, Drupal doesn't know this param and cannot load the corresponding node object, which results in fatal errors.

How can make I this work?
I tried to implement a custom `RoutingParamConverter` class, but I didn't got it to work.

Answer (score 17):

As long as you have the uuid of an entity you can use Drupal's entity storage interface to load it given that property. It should be as simple as using the loadByProperties method.

```
$node_loaded_by_uuid = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties(['uuid' => $your_uuid]);
$node_loaded_by_uuid = reset($node_loaded_by_uuid);
```

UPDATE: milkovsky is correct. [loadByProperties](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.2.x) returns an array. If you want the actual node object at the top of it you will have to use the reset function.

Comment: You will get an array back. A `reset(...)` operation should be done in addiiton: `$node_loaded_by_uuid = reset($node_loaded_by_uuid)`.

Comment: @milkovsky thank you. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: See my answer for something simpler.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [EntityRepositoryInterface::loadEntityByUuid()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityRepositoryInterface.php/function/EntityRepositoryInterface%3A%3AloadEntityByUuid/8.9.x):

```php
$entity = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid('node', $uuid);
```

Comment: The internals of the `loadEntityByUuid` function does exactly what the other answer is doing, but with a couple extra calls. See `loadEntityByUuid` in EntityRepository.php

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. I have a hook_node_presave() and I need the Node ID but only have the UUID. 
Working on Drupal 9.5 and will test for Drupal 10.x after the migration.

`$entity = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid('node', 'b6bca440-f4d9-41d0-86c6-d913c00b9e78')->id();`

Everything I need is there!